# Open Sans Light bleeding

Tags: css, fonts

I'm having troubles rendering the google Open Sans font on my website.

I used fontsquirrel to convert the open sans font to woff, woff2 and svg.
Using the cdn loader doesnt work for chrome, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145620/google-font-weight-300-not-working).

When I'm using small font and open_sanslight I'm getting this(top is regular bottom is light, you can see that the i in "mins" is bleeding pretty bad):

[image]

I already tried adding svg but it didn't help. Is there any way to get rid of the bleeding?

Comment: Have you considered loading the font from Google Fonts, instead of locally?

Comment: Are you sure this is reproducable? I've had simular issues but that was my Windows font setting rather then the font itself.

Comment: It is, its the same problem on a mac. 
@AdamMcquiff please check out my link concerning the cdn loader